# Saving Selenium Chrome session c#

Tags: c#, selenium

guys im trying to download cache from my chrome browser to a certain file. i've been looking on google and here and i didn't find any result. so please i need someone to show me how to do that

Answer (score 0):

Use this code :

```
Set<Cookie>  cookie = driver.manage().getCookies();
    for(Cookie c : cookie){
        //write each cookie to your file.
      }
```

Comment: this is for java i think not for c#

Comment: Yes it is in java . Can you mapped this into C#?

Answer (score 0):

I think here code c# you need!

```
public string getCookie()
        {
            string fCookie ="";
            var cookies = driver.Manage().Cookies.AllCookies.ToArray();
            foreach (OpenQA.Selenium.Cookie cookie in cookies)
            {
                fCookie += "cookie Name: " + cookie.Name +" cookie Value: " + cookie.Value +"\r\n";
            }            
            return fCookie;
        }
```